# Iptables working strangely

Tags: iptables

I  have Ubuntu 12.04 x64 installed in my laptop.

I'm quite new to linux, and I wanted to specify certain rules for the iptables firewall.

This is the saved config of my iptables:

---

```
*mangle

:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

COMMIT


*nat

:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:3306

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11002 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:11002

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 13000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:13000

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 13001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:13001

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 13002 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:13002

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 13003 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:13003

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 13004 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:13004

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 13061 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:13061

-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 13099 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:13099

-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT


*filter

:INPUT DROP [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT


-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

---

In theory, what it does is to drop all connections in all ports except for http, mysql and few other ports.

Moreover, it redirects all mysql and 13000-13004..etc port connections to a specific local ip in the same port, which is 192.168.1.100.

But what I find strange is that when my firewall is active, it blocks absolutely all the input connections, even those which must not block (http, mysql). In fact, I'm literally blocked and I can't establish any external connection.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I tested the firewall without those redirections, and it still block all inputs, so I suppose it's not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first and for all you need to check if forwarding packets is allowed on your system:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or

```
sysctl ipv4_forward
```

This should have the value of '1'. if not (sudo or as root):

```
echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

and to make the change permanent you can uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Once this has been done you can further test your iptables settings (I presume that it will work after that minor change ;-)). Since you said that you where new to this I've placed a description of the rule under each rule hoping it all makes a bit sense to you.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD ACCEPT
```

This will drop all traffic except traffic that matches the rules that are defined. -P INPUT DROP can be stated as the first rule whereas -A INPUT DROP has to be the last. 
The next 2 rules will allow outgoing connections and forwarding.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Allow loopback (127.0.0.1) traffic

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELEATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This will allow all packets that have state RELATED (A new secondary connection f.e. FTP) or ESTABLISHED (packets for this connection has been seen in both directions f.e. HTTP traffic).

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ethx -j MASQUERADE
```

nat because you probably are natting , masquerade the packet going OUT of interface `ethx`. F.e.: WAN side is on eth1 and lan on eth0 so ethx would be eth0. This is on the POSTROUTING.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:3306
```

this is the actual forwarding.

So basicly your iptables rules where OK, you probably just forgot the ip_forward setting.

Comment: Thank you very much Goez, that was the problem. The reason I didn't check it was because I did change it to 1 the day before. What I didn't know is the fact that this setting became 0 again after rebooting. Now I've made a script that does it for me each time I boot.
Thanks again!

Comment: @user109985 A common approach would be putting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` so that it survives after rebooting.